# How to delete rows on source right after they were pushed into an array (Sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, delete-row

How to make to make it delete the rows that match a criteria and were pushed into an array?

So far, I got the following, but it gives me out of bounds error:

```
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
         if (values[i][0] == productCode) {
        data.push([values[i][22],values[i][23],values[i][24],values[i][25]]); //This array is for a certain purpose.
        headerData.push(headerValues[i]);//This array is for another certain purpose.
        sheet.deleteRow(i+1); //This is the one I'm having trouble with.    
    } 
  }
```

On Source sheet, I got headers

I've seen that delete row actually works from bottom to top, but how I can re-reference i rows within that for loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Loop backwards:

```
  for (var i = (values.length-1); i > 0; i--) {
         if (values[i][0] == productCode) {
        data.push([values[i][22],values[i][23],values[i][24],values[i][25]]); //This array is for a certain purpose.
        headerData.push(headerValues[i]);//This array is for another certain purpose.
        sheet.deleteRow(i+1); //This is the one I'm having trouble with.    
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! It's giving me a "Cannot read property '0' of undefined on row if (values[i][0] == productCode) {...
Any idea as to why?

Comment: I just updated my code - the reason is that the value length is 1 bigger than the highest value index, since the array starts with [0].

Comment: It worked!
Too much abstraction at once for me to absorb! I'll spend some time trying to grasp what seems to be so clear to you!
Danke!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like that:

```
let headerData = []
let data = [];
const headerSize = 1;
for (let i = values.length - 1; i > headerSize; i--) {
  if (values[i][0] === productCode) {
    let row = [values[i][22],values[i][23],values[i][24],values[i][25]] 
    data = [row, ...data]
    headerData = [headerValues[i], ...headerData]    
    sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
  } 
}
```

use destructuring arrays to keep the values in order