# Google Script- how to stop a loop if 7 cells are blank in a row

Tags: loops, for-loop, google-apps-script, is-empty

I am wondering if there is a way to break; a loop when a predetermined number of cells return blank. The issue is that I have to set my i variable to 100 because that is the most employees possible however it is also possible that we have far fewer currently employed. I do not want the loop to take forever with no data.

```
 function current5(){
  
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var issued = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Issued");
  for(var i=1;i<100;i++){
    var firstCell = issued.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    if(firstCell === ""){
      issued.deleteRow(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can do it with an auxilliary counter

- Make the counter increase when an empty row is found
- Reset it to `0` if a non-empty row is found
- [Break](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp) out of the loop if the counter reaches the value `7`

```js
function current5(){
  
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var issued = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Issued");
  var empty = 0;
  for(var i=1;i<100;i++){
    var firstCell = issued.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    if(firstCell == ""){
      empty++;
    }
    else{
      empty = 0;
    }
    if(empty >= 7){
      Logger.log(issued.getRange(i,1).getA1Notation());
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:**

- Be very careful if you want to delete rows
- Because deletion of a row makes you skip the next row
- If you want to felte rows, you need to either loop backwards or manually decrease `i` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61482375/11599789)